# How can i print out associative array in Php

Tags: php

I'm basically trying to print out each item in the associative array.

I'm mostly having problems with getting the 2nd foreach to test the length of each array within the array.

This my code so far:

```
<?

$kwame = array (
    1=>array('Html','Php','Javascript','Java','CSS'),
    2=>array('Saran','Darissa','Patricia'),
    3=>array('Macbook','Iphone 6','Water Jug'));


$arrayl = count($kwame);
$num1l = count($kwame[1]);
$num2l = count($kwame[2]);
$num3l = count($kwame[3]);


for($i=1; $i<=$arrayl; $i++){

for($x=0; $x<=$num1l; $x++){
    echo $kwame[$i][$x].' ';
}

echo '<br>';

}

?>
```

Comment: I think your main difficulty here is the fact that you _aren't_ using `foreach` as your question implies, but rather an incremental `for` loop.  Incremental loops like this are infrequently needed in PHP, where iteration is better done with `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Need something like this? Not sure.

```
    $kwame = array (
    1=>array('Html','Php','Javascript','Java','CSS'),
    2=>array('Saran','Darissa','Patricia'),
    3=>array('Macbook','Iphone 6','Water Jug'));


foreach($kwame as $row) {
    foreach($row as $row2) {
        echo $row2." ";
    }
    echo "<br />";    
}
```

Comment: I would just `echo implode(" ", $row)` here instead of appending the `|` which will leave one trailing on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `foreach` loops:

```
foreach ($kwame as $outer) {
    foreach ($outer as $inner) {
        echo $inner.' ';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

You can also remove the inner loop by `implode`ing the values:

```
foreach ($kwame as $array) {
    echo implode(' ', $array), '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying using PHP's `foreach`? It iterates each array, giving you the content of each iteration of the array in a variable specified, in a sense.

(**Warning:** Untested code)

```
//Iterate the first array, to get the inner arrays.
foreach($kwame as $array_elem){
  //For each inner array get its elements.
  foreach($array_elem as $inner_array_elem){
    //Print each inner array element.
    echo $inner_array_elem." ";
  }
  //Print a new line between each inner array data.
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

That way, you do not need to use the number of elements of each array or use counters to index them "classically".

Answer (score 0):

What about this ...

```
    <?php

    $kwames = array (
        1=>array('Html','Php','Javascript','Java','CSS'),
        2=>array('Saran','Darissa','Patricia'),
        3=>array('Macbook','Iphone 6','Water Jug')
    );

    foreach ($kwames as $id => $kwame) {
         echo '<pre>';
         echo count($kwame) . '</br>';
         foreach ($kwame as $kwameitem) {
                echo $kwameitem . '</br>';

         }

         echo '</pre>';
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Where is your foreach loop? I don't see it.

```
<?php
$kwame = array(
    1 => array('Html', 'Php', 'Javascript', 'Java', 'CSS'),
    2 => array('Saran', 'Darissa', 'Patricia'),
    3 => array('Macbook', 'Iphone 6', 'Water Jug'));

foreach($kwame as $foo) { // here is an example for foreach
    echo $foo[0]; // prints first array's values
    echo $foo[1]; // prints second array's values
    echo $foo[2]; // prints third array's values
}
?>
```

Comment: It will output ArayArrayArray if you don't specify the array's index. Here is the result I got : http://i.imgur.com/kgtIF42.png  I am new in PHP, though.
edit : There was a comment on my answer, it has been deleted.